# c# IIS perfomanceCounter always returns 0

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I trying to get uptime for IIS AppPool, but code always returns zero. Windows system monitor shows real values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7yZh.png)

There is my code:

```cs
public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    TaskCompletionSource<HealthCheckResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HealthCheckResult>();

    try
    {
        PerformanceCounterCategory cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("APP_POOL_WAS");
        string inst = cat.GetInstanceNames().First(x => x.Contains("bp"));
        PerformanceCounter pc = cat.GetCounters(inst).First(x => x.CounterName == "Total Application Pool Uptime");
        float val = pc.NextValue(); //zero 
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        val = pc.NextValue(); //zero too
        tcs.SetResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy($"Last AppPool uptime: {val}"));
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exc, $"Error on RebootCheck: {exc.Message}");
        tcs.SetException(exc);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

aspnet 5.0, windows 10, run code in Rider with elevated privileges
Another check - system uptime counter - works fine

Powershell also got correct counetr values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m4OK.png)

Comment: Where have you written this code? And how is it being called?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya update my question. I called it from aspnet HealthChecks, in self-hosted service aspnet 5.0

Comment: try to assign the IIS APPPOOL\poolname to the performance manager user group. after making changes restart the machine.set load user profile to false in iis

Comment: Do I really need this? Powershell got counter: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3338705/106446244-11680f80-6491-11eb-804e-f80bae1998d6.png

Comment: It looks like the PowerShell module uses native interop with pdh.dll to get this, and doesn't use the .NET PerformanceCounter types.  So this may be a deficiency in the .NET library. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/using-the-pdh-functions-to-consume-counter-data  You can decompile the GAC'd version to see: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics